# How do I check whether a string is NULL?

Tags: typescript, nullable

I am new to Typescript and am unsure how to check whether a string paramter is `null` or not.

The `concat` function below is exported for use by other Typescript modules. I want like to generate an error message if either string parameter is `null`. Am I doing it correctly?

```js
export const concat = (a: string, b: string) => {
    if ((typeof a === null) || (typeof b === null)) { throw new Error(' A is missing')}

    if ((a === '') || (b === '')) { throw new Error(' A is missing')}

    return a.concat(b);
}

describe ('concat', () => {
  it('Should concat these two strings', ()=> {
    const result=concat('He','llo')
    expect(result).to.equal('Hello');
  })
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with your commented code?

Answer (score 3):

Typescript *is* Javascript with optional type assertions and checking layered on. You check for `null` in the exact same way.

But Typescript gives you another option: disallow `null`s in the first place. In fact, that's what your function's parameter declaration already does: `(a: string, b: string)` means both `a` and `b` must only be string, never `null`.

If, for example, you changed it to `(a: string | null, b: string)`, it would mean `a` can be null, though `b` still can't.

So if you keep your function's parameters the way you have it, you don't need to do the `null` check. If you want to allow nulls, then you need to add `| null` to the type assertions.

All that said, if you expect that some other users of your library will use Javascript not Typescript, and you want to guard against them passing in `null`, then you would keep the null checks, even though they would be redundant for Typescript.

Let me know if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    export const concat = (a: string, b: string) => {
     if ((a == null) || (b == null)) { throw new Error('A is missing')}

     if ((a === '') || (b === '')) { throw new Error('A is missing')}

           return a.concat(b);
    }
```

Just remove the `typeof`.
Using `==` makes it possible to check both if the input is `null` or `undefinded`.